# Datagridview doubles and sorting

Tags: c#, datagridview

Hi I have a datagridview.
I am adding manually some doubles to it, and after that I want to sort it, but when i run this line of code:

```
this.dgv.Sort(this.dgv.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending)
```

I have information that "Object must be of type String."
I am not binding dgv, and I am adding rows programmatically
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try use this.dgv.Columns["colName"] not index. And show how you adding columns.

Comment: That's not it. Same result.
I am addings rows as this:
dgv.Rows.Add(value);

Comment: how do you add 'some doubles' to your Dgv?

Comment: Are you using ValueType? Show how you add column[0]. Try use this.dgv.Columns[0].ValueType = typeof(System.Double) during adding columns

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found error in my code.
I was filling datagridview with:

```
dgv.Rows.Add(myReader[0]);
```

and then I was adding new rows like this:

```
dgv.Rows.Add(value); //where value is double...
```

I needed to change first part to:

```
dgv.Rows.Add(double.Parse(myReader[0].ToString());
```

Thank you for help.